# SQL table with Day, Date, Month, Year, Period, Week Number? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, getdate

I had created a table long time ago using SQL that had Day, Month, Year, Weekday, Date, and Period (example: April 2016).
This is what my current table looks like:

```
|   Period   | Day | Month | Year | Weekday |    Date   |
|:-----------|-----|-------|------|---------|----------:|
| April 2016 | 21  | April |2016  |Thursday |2016-04-21 |
```

Now I am needing to add **Week** (it is week 1, 2,... of that current month).

This select statement gives the correct result:

`SELECT datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 0), GETDATE() - 1) + 1`

This query returns

```
4
```

How do I insert a new column called **Week** into this existing table and have it find the current week number?

I believe that the existing table is using `GETDATE()` to calculate its values. Unfortunately I do not have my CREATE query anymore.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Unfortunately I do not have my CREATE query anymore.` Use SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the table and generate the create script

Comment: Is that Right-click> Script Table as> CREATE To> New Query Editor Window? If so, that just creates the columns but doesn't set their calculated values :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a column for `week` using `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD Week int
```

Then `UPDATE` the column with the week number:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Week = DATEPART(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date])/7 * 7)/7 + 1
```

Note: This `week` number is based on the day number alone, not the days of the week (Monday, Tuesday) etc.